# Recursively calling a function until a desired input is achieved

Tags: java, recursion

The method getHtmlFromUrl sometimes results in an Exception. Sometimes, however, it outputs a String. How would I call the function obtainWorkingHtml as few times as possible, such that I get a String from it as quickly as possible?

So far, I have tried basic try/catch recursion. I have heard something about attempting to use a do { statement, but do not know where to go from there.

```
  public static String obtainWorkingHtml() throws Exception {
    try {
      String randomUrl = "https://www." + randomWord() + ".com";
      return getHtmlFromUrl(randomUrl);

    } catch(Exception e) {
      return obtainWorkingHtml();
    }
  }
```

As is, the program ALWAYS yields a String. It sometimes takes very long but it always does. Ideally, it would take less.

EDIT: I am essentially trying to obtain HTML data from websites that may or may not exist. This can result in a variety of errors, so I have not defined my expected exception, if that matters.

Comment: In my eyes, this is one of the cases where recursion is a very bad idea! You do not have a *real* termination condition, so you stack can be indefinitely deep … Do you insist in a recursive solution, or are you seeking in a solution that works with an iterative loop?

Comment: @tquadrat I am fine with any solution. I just want the function to return a String every single time, relatively quickly.

Comment: @KingSpikeAqua can you share your randomWord() code too

Comment: @fuzious Not relevant to the issue really. It is exactly as you would expect; a random String for a website name.

Comment: @KingSpikeAqua: How fast the method `obtainWorkingHtml()` is depends only from `randomWord()` and how fast it will produce a valid URL. Ok, perhaps you can make `getHtmlFromUrl()` a bit more fast-failing, but in the method in question itself, you cannot gain more speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion is a bad idea if the level of recursion is unlimited/undeterministic. Recursion depth is limited by stack size and at some point you will get a StackOverflowError. For the same effect but without stack overflow possibilities, empty your `catch` block and wrap the `try/catch` inside a `while(true)` block.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would look like this:

```
public static String obtainWorkingHtml()
{
    String retValue = null;
    while( retValue == null )
    {
        final var randomUrl = "https://www." + randomWord() + ".com";
        try 
        {
            retValue = getHtmlFromUrl( randomUrl );
        }
        catch( Exception e ) { /* Deliberately ignored */ }
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

It will still run forever if `getHtmlFromUrl()` will never come back with some useful response, but at least it will not nuke the stack.